# What does "booty-trap" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain to me what *booty-trap* means in this sentence?

> We moved back in there, setting up booty traps. Each man booty-trapped his own home.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary has a (typically obscene) definition of "booty-trap" here http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=booty-trap , but I can't see how you could set up one of those. Are you quite sure you don't mean "booby-trap"?

Comment: "That's what I said!, setting booty-traps"

Comment: "booty trap" sounds like To Catch A Predator.

Comment: Yeah, a "booty trap" is some sort of sexual trap.  The proper term is "booby trap", if you're talking about some sort of "snare" or "pitfall" trap.  However, I don't doubt that there are a million or so people who think that "booty trap" is the correct term, and so that term might be legitimately used if some dialect is being reflected in dialog.

Answer (score 10):

"Booty-trap" probably more means "[booby trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booby_trap)" in that sentence.

Booty has several meanings: it can mean "a treasure under the sea" for instance and it's also an American Slang term for "buttock".

I cannot think of any (not too contrived) interpretation of "booty-trap" that would
involve either of these two meanings. Say for instance a soldier gets into a house and there is a treasure waiting for him.  I know this is the right day for this kind of prank...but somehow I doubt that was the intended meaning.

Rather, in the context you cite, this means that each man of a troop from a village formerly searched by alien forces came back after the invaders have left and sets up an improvised explosive device so that if invaders come back again they get wounded or worse.  An example of such a device is a grenade that would explode when someone opens the door of a cupboard.  Each man goes in his own house because he knows it well and he can decide what will be damaged by the trap. This technique has been very commonly used recently in Afghanistan and Iraq but was also used during last century's WWII.  It's a feature of [Asymmetric Warfare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_warfare).

The original meaning of "booby-trap" is that of a schoolboy's practical joke to trap boobies.  A booby in that sense has nothing to do with the gannet species but must be understood as "dummy/simpleton/fool."

Answer (score 2):

This looks as if it came from an al-Jazeera interview about Gaza (see [partial transcript](http://israelmatzav.blogspot.com/2009/03/gaza-each-man-booby-trapped-his-own.html)) and it was "booby trap".